# How to detect double blue v mark over a regular double v mark in WhatsApp web site?

Tags: java, html, maven, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am doing now WhatsApp web scraping project using selenium in Java (only for educational purposes) ,and I am facing with a problem when I try to detect the double blue v mark after the double grey v mark.
The problem is that the message log shows a status message that the message got read by the target user even if it does not entered the conversation . It is strange because the method just ignores the third wait command while it differs between the  blue v mark and the regular one.
Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Here is the essential code :

private void checkMessageStatus() {
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));

```
    try {
        // Check if the message got one check mark (message delivered to the server)
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(Constants.SINGLE_V_XPATH)));
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            messageLog.append("The message got one V.\n");
            messageLog.setCaretPosition(messageLog.getDocument().getLength());
            messageLog.repaint();
        });

        // Check if the message got two check marks (message delivered to the recipient's phone)
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(Constants.DOUBLE_V_XPATH)));
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            messageLog.append("The message got double V.\n");
            messageLog.setCaretPosition(messageLog.getDocument().getLength());
            messageLog.repaint();
        });

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(Constants.DOUBLE_BLUE_V_XPATH)));
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            messageLog.append("The message got double blue V.\n");
            messageLog.setCaretPosition(messageLog.getDocument().getLength());
            messageLog.repaint();
        });

        // Delay the execution of the next block of code
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        scheduledExecutorService.schedule(() -> {
            // Close the browser
            // driver.quit();
        }, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the essential constants that represent the xPaths :
public static final String SINGLE_V_XPATH = "(//span[@data-icon='msg-check'])[last()]";
public static final String DOUBLE_V_XPATH = "(//span[@data-icon='msg-dblcheck'])[last()]";
public static final String DOUBLE_BLUE_V_XPATH = "(//span[@class='S7n_s'])[last()]";